# Finding the probability of getting a particular remainder.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have started studying number theory, and came across the following problem (as a side note, I am not very familiar with modular arithmetic yet, so it would be interesting to see if you can do this problem easily without it).

“A natural number is picked at random.

First, the number is doubled,

Then the result is squared,

Finally, the result is divided by 6.

Find the probability that the remainder is 4.”

I was taught to solve this problem by trying values of n and then seeing a pattern. Doing this, you notice that the remainders cycle in a series of 4,4,0 therefore showing that the probability of it being 4, is 2/3.

However, this doesn’t really satisfy me, and I was wondering if there was a more algebraic way to approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the picked random natural number be $x$, you want $4x^2$ to give a remainder of $4$, when divided by $6$.
$$\Longrightarrow 4x^2=6k+4$$
for some integer $k$.
$$\Longrightarrow 2x^2=3k+2$$
Now, $3k=2(x^2-1)$. Hence, $3k$ and ultimately $k$ is even. Let $k=2l$.
$$\Longrightarrow x^2=3l+1$$
So, you want $x^2$ to give a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$, which happens iff $3\not\mid x$. Since, every third natural number is divisible by $3$, required probability is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Wow thanks, just what I was looking for.